# Label styling applied in Geoserver are not being applied to WMS layer in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, sld

I am trying to label a layer of line vectors using SLD in Geoserver. It is simple enough, and it's pretty much copied from the SLD cookbook: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html

The thing that's getting me is that when I view the Openlayers preview in Geoserver, everything seems to render correctly. Each road is only labeled once and it's not extremely busy looking. However, when I import the layer via WMS to my Openlayers map, it doesn't seem to recognize this line:

```
<VendorOption name="repeat">400</VendorOption>
```

Which is supposed to keep it from repeating within 400 pixels.

I've also tried:

```
<VendorOption name="group">yes</VendorOption>
```

Which should only display a single label on a map per unique text.

Any idea what is going on here? I need the labels to look like the Geoserver preview.

Map displayed in openlayers after importing layer via WMS:
[image: WMS Served Map]

Map displayed in Geoserver Openlayers preview:
[image: Openlayers preview]

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Roads</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Roads</Title>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:Literal>#000000</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
           <Label>
             <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
           </Label>
           <LabelPlacement>
             <LinePlacement>
               <PerpendicularOffset>
                 10
               </PerpendicularOffset>
             </LinePlacement>
           </LabelPlacement>
           <Fill>
             <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
           </Fill>
         <VendorOption name="repeat">400</VendorOption>
        </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an artifact due to tiling. The layer preview map defaults to a single tile, but I'm guessing your openlayers map uses tiling.

Geoserver insists on labeling every tile. GeoServer doesn't know that each request is for a tile in a larger map, so it treats a tile as a complete map and dutifully applies a label to it. So basically, if a road stretches across three tiles, it will be labelled three times.

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do about it. I was advised to enable meta-tiling. This does allow GeoServer to think of requests as tile components to some extent, and this can minimise the label repeating. However, I believe it's on by default in recent versions.

Comment: You are right, it is due to tiling. I found that in the Openlayers preview you can click the button in the top left in order to change it to single tile or tiled; when changing to tiled it showed the same problems. 

This is how I resolved it: 

When adding the WMS layer in openlayers, you have to specify the "tiled: true, tilesorigin: [map.maxExtent.left, map.maxExtent.bottom]" parameters. 

Finally, in the Geoserver layer tile caching tab, you can change the metatiling factors to something larger than 4x4.

Comment: Thanks, @scavok! by larger than 4x4 you mean 5x5? Does it seem more labels will be repeated as the number of tiles increased?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on Ol side

```
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Image";
import ImageWMS from 'ol/source/ImageWMS';
import { geoserverURL } from '../config';

const BuildingWMS = new TileLayer({
    source: new ImageWMS({
        ratio:1,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        url: `${geoserverURL}/wms?`,
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'Baku:Buildings',
            'FORMAT': 'image/png',
            'VERSION': '1.1.1',
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    }),
    visible: true,
    name: 'BuildingWMS'
});
export {
    BuildingWMS
};
```